# In which situation does function prototype have to include parameter names?

Tags: c, function

I am studying the C programming language by K&R and there is a exercise as below:

Exercise 3-5: Write the function itob(n, s, b) that converts the integer n into a base b character representation in the string s. In particular, itob(n, s, 16) formats n as a hexadecimal integer in s.

So I wrote program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

void reverse(char );
void itob(int , char , int );

main()
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int n, i;
    printf("integer: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&n);
    printf("base: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&i);
    itob(n, line, i);
    printf("%s", line);
}

void itob(int n, char s[], int b)
{
    int i, sign;

    if ((sign = n) < 0)
        n = -n;
    i = 0;
    do 
    {

        n % b < 10 ? (s[i++] = n % b + '0') : (s[i++] = n % b + '7');
    }
    while ((n /= b) > 0);
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}

void reverse(char s[])
{
    int c, i, j;

    for  (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
}
```

I thought everything was OK. But when I ran the program, I got error after I input integer and base values, like below:

> Unhandled exception at 0x10022050 (msvcr110d.dll) in Exercise 3-5.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000EC.

So the program had trouble with function itob call.

And then after about 2 hour struggle for debugging, I found the cause was the function prototype of reverse need to include parameter name like this:

```
void reverse(char s[]);
void itob(int , char , int );
```

The only change I made was I added s[] in the function prototype of reverse and then program worked properly.

I am confused because all I learned is that parameter names of function prototype are optional. Why does the parameter name have to include in function prototype of reverse? And why does function prototype of itob not need parameter name and there is not pop-up error? My IDE is Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks for everyone's time and help.

Comment: The `[]` is not part of the *name*.

Comment: Why are you writing crap code - horrors such as `if ((sign = n) < 0)` and `n % b < 10 ? (s[i++] = n % b + '0') : (s[i++] = n % b + '7');`

Comment: The answer to your title question is _never_.

Comment: Compiling your code with clang, I got 4 warnings and 2 errors. I can't believe that VS2012 accepts that code with no warnings or errors. Check the compiler settings, and make sure that you compile with `-W4`, and never ever ignore warnings.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I'm a c beginner and programming beginner. I followed examples in the book to write this program. I didn't pay attention to the warning. Actually I got 3 warnings after compiled but no errors. Thanks for comments.

Comment: By adding the s[], you changed the declaration to a char *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question has a number of bugs, many of which your compiler should have at least warned you about.

When I copied the code and compiled it using gcc, even without any additional arguments, the first error message was:

```
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:16:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘itob’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     itob(n, line, i);
     ^
c.c:6:6: note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void itob(int , char , int );
      ^
```

The error message is correct. You declared `itob` with a second parameter of type `char`, then called it with a second parameter of type `char*` (resulting from the implicit conversion of the array `line`).

Later, you *define* `itob` with a second parameter of type `char[]` (which, since it's a parameter, is really of type `char*`). This is incompatible with the earlier declaration, and it should also have been flagged by your compiler.

To answer the question in your title, in a standalone prototype (one that's not part of the function definition), parameter names are optional.  These two prototypes are equivalent and valid:

```
void itob(int, char, int);
```

and

```
void itob(int x, char y, int z);
```

Personally I like to specify parameter names just because it makes the code clearer.

For a prototype that's part of a function definition, the names are required, because that's how the parameter objects are defined.

But first, fix the errors in your code.

Comment: Everything you say is fine, except you missed one case.  An argument that is not used by a function is not required to be named in the argument list even in the function definition.   This is used, for example, when an argument is intended for future extension but not currently used - without having to jump through more arcane hoops to stop the compiler warning about a named argument being unused.

Comment: @Peter: I believe that's true in C++ but not in C.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for your information. I got 3 warnings when I compile it and was just ignore them. I did not get errors so I thought the code did not have bugs. For your comment can you explain more about difference between standalone prototype and "non-standalone" prototype?? What's the meaning of "one that is/not part of the function definition"?

Comment: A function definition defines what the function does; it includes the `{` ... `}`. Do *not* just ignore warnings; in many cases, C compilers will issue warnings for things that IMHO should be treated as fatal errors.

Comment: "I did not get errors so I thought the code did not have bugs" – even when code compiles without *any* warnings or errors, that does **not** automatically mean it doesn't contain bugs! If only that were true...